# How can I download user input as a file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I already have.

```html
Username: <input type "text" id="inp" />
<p id="res"></p>

Password: <input type "text" id="inp" />
<p id="res"></p>

<a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>

<button type="button">Download</button>
```

I would like it to download the two inputs username and password into a file
and stop popup if possible

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use duplicate `id's` in your HTML code, then try to attach an `input` event to your input's so every time you type inside one of them the value of `href` will be generated automatically constructing the link to your file with the typed data :

**jQuery solution :**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input').on('input', function() {
        var data = $('#inp1').val() + "\n" + $('#inp2').val();

        $('a#downloadlink').show().attr('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data));
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Username: <input type "text" id="inp1" />
  <p id="res1"></p>

  Password: <input type "text" id="inp2" />
  <p id="res2"></p>

  <a href="" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the JS code:

```
function downloadFile() {
    var obj = {a: <INPUT_1>, b: <INPUT_2>};
    var filename = "download.json";
    var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj)], {type: 'text/plain'});
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    } else{
        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = filename;
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', a.download, a.href].join(':');
        e.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="downloadFile();" value="Download">
```

Find the completed code below:

```
    <html>

    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        function downloadFile() {
    var obj = {a: "<INPUT_1>", b: "<INPUT_2>"};
    var filename = "download.json";
    var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj)], {type: 'text/plain'});
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    } else{
        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = filename;
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', a.download, a.href].join(':');
        e.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      Username: <input type "text" id="inp1" />
      <p id="res1"></p>

      Password: <input type "text" id="inp2" />
      <p id="res2"></p>

      <input type="button" onclick="downloadFile();" value="Download">
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: your code seems very good but were do i have to place the function?

Comment: You can keep the function in the `<script></script>` tags of your html

Comment: and were is downloading?

Comment: I have updated the code above. Also currently I am downloading json file. Hope u can fix the rest

Answer (score 0):

this is the end result thanks for your help

```
<head>

    <title> test </title>

    
    
    
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload=function(){
    (function () {
    var textFile = null,
    makeTextFile = function (text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
    if (textFile !== null) {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }
    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    return textFile;
    };
    
    var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    email = document.getElementById('email');
    var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    password = document.getElementById('password');
    
    create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    
    link.href = makeTextFile(email.value + password.value);
    
    link.style.display = 'block';
    }, false);
    })();
    }
    </script>
    
    
    
    
</head>

<body>

    Username:<input id="email">
    <p id="res1"></p>
    Password:<input id="password">
    <p id="res2"></p>
    
    
    <button id="create">Login</button><a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
    
    
    
    <script>
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
    height: document.body.getBounthingClientRect().height,
    slug: "qm5AG"
    }], "*")
    }
    </script>
    

</body>
```